# Impulse and car make (homework question)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, momentum

In my physics course it says that the more sturdy the car is the more momentum change (impulse) it will experience during a collision.
The following image is a snippet of the paragraph in my course that talks about this.

> These different types of collisions can have a serious effect on people in cars. Usually, a car collision is inelastic or completely inelastic, if the vehicles stay together. Older cars were made to be very sturdy, with solid metal frames. This caused collisions to occur over shorter periods of time, and the cars to bounce back. These two factors increased the net force experienced by passengers because the change in momentum was larger and it happened over a shorter period of time.
>
> Modern cars have "crumple zones" in the front and rear. These serve to lengthen the time of impact for the collision, as well as to absorb as much energy as possible, which decreases the chance that the cars will bounce off each other and increase the impulse. Both these factors decrease the net force on passengers, helping to reduce the number of injuries and deaths.

Why is this the case? Impulse should not change with the material the car is made from but only with the amount of seconds it is contact with the other car and the force (action-reaction) between the two cars.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. The text explicitly relates the material to the amount of time of the collision. What specific part of the text doesn't make sense to you?

Also, please type out the relevant part of the text; images are not accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impulse is simply the change in an object's momentum. When two cars collide and bounce off one another (an elastic collision), the impulse is greater than when two cars collide and stop (an inelastic collision). When the cars bounce off one another, they require enough impulse to stop the car, and then *even more* impulse to make them bounce back the way they came. The crumple zone reduces the *total impulse* by preventing the cars from bouncing back, as well as increasing the time and thereby decreasing the force required to achieve that momentum change. The crumple zone reduces the force felt by passengers both by reducing the total momentum change, and lengthening the time over which that change occurs.

Comment: Concise and to the point. I love this explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this the case? Impulse should not change with the material the
> car is made from but only with the amount of seconds it is contact
> with the other car and the force (action-reaction) between the two
> cars.

Designing cars with crumple zones extends the stopping time/distance during a collision. This lessens the average impact force experienced by the occupants, due to the work energy theorem: The net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Or

$$F_{net}d=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Where $F_{net}$ = the average impact force, $d$ = the stopping distance and $v$ = the velocity of the car just prior to impact. The crumpling of the car extends the stopping distance $d$ and therefore lowers the average impact force, for the same change in kinetic energy.

For more background on this principle and additional examples of its application, see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/work.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lengthening the collision time is only half the answer - the crumple zone also prevents the collision from being elastic, which requires a larger impulse than an inelastic one. Even in a car with no crumple zone, you'd prefer to just hit an object and stop, rather than bouncing backwards. The total impulse is less in the inelastic collision, but the total momentum change doesn't depend on the collision duration. A strong magnet or glue or some other method of "sticking" to objects you hit could mimic this benefit of the crumple zone without changing the collision distance/duration at all.